# Black Jack game multiple round system

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack

So me and my friend are making a blackjack game and I have trouble with making the game multiple rounds long, so after the round has ended the next round starts. I don't know how to do it. This is my code:

```
starter_chips = 500

print(f"You have {starter_chips} chips")
bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet: "))


input_chips = starter_chips - bet
even_score_chips = input_chips + bet

print(f"You have {input_chips} left")

dealer_cards = 17
player_cards = 17

if player_cards == dealer_cards:
    print(f"You get your bet back and have {even_score_chips} chips")
```

After this I want to start the next round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to wrap your existing code for a hand with a `while` loop that asks if the play would like to continue playing. Using your code as a starting point you might do:

```
user_chips = int(input("How many chips do you start with?: "))

## --------------------------
## continue playing until you "break" out of this loop
## You could do also loop based on a variable that is initially true but changes to false to stop
## --------------------------
while True:
    print(f"You have {user_chips} chips")
    user_bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet: "))

    ## --------------------------
    ## adjust the player's chip total based on bet
    ## --------------------------
    user_chips -= user_bet
    ## --------------------------

    ## --------------------------
    ## deal out several rounds of cards
    ## --------------------------
    dealer_total = 17
    player_total = 17
    ## --------------------------

    ## --------------------------
    ## Act on final totals
    ## --------------------------
    if player_total == dealer_total:
        print(f"You and the dealer both have {player_total}. Your bet of {user_bet} is returned to you")
        user_chips += user_bet
    ## --------------------------

    ## --------------------------
    ## Ask the user if they would like to continue playing and if not "break" to force an exit from the while loop.
    ## --------------------------
    if input("Play again? (y|n): ").lower() != "y":
        break
    ## --------------------------
## --------------------------

print(f"You leave the table with {user_chips} chips.")
```